# How can I programmatically test if SQL Server supports 'AT TIME ZONE'?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm currently using SQL CLR for timezone conversions in SQL Server and because it's an unsafe assembly I can't run it in Azure. It's a business requirement that we support on-premise and Azure. I'm thinking of using the AT TIME ZONE functionality for Azure and retaining SQL CLR for on-premise.

I'd like to be able to add a single sql function that uses 'AT TIME ZONE' if available that otherwise calls the assembly, if possible.

I could just run a test query using the syntax before running the sql to create the function and create another if there's an error... but this would mean that a backup of one instance may contain errors if loaded into an older sql server version that doesn't support the syntax (e.g. 2016 to 2014).

What is the best practice method for testing (preferably within the SQL statement itself) whether the database supports this syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AT TIME ZONE is a new feature available in SQL Server 2016 (starting with CTP 3.1) and in the latest version of Azure SQL Database (V12). 
It is also available in all on-prem editions of SQL2016 and in all service tiers of Azure SQL database.
Having said that, the best way to determine if AT TIME ZONE is supported is to check server version by running the following query

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') as Edition
       SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')as VersionNumber
```

If Edition = 'SQL Azure' than VersionNumber has to be >= '12'

If Edition != 'SQL Azure' than Version Number has to be >= '13.0.800.000' (CTP 3.1)

For more details on SERVER property check out MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms174396.aspx

Thanks,
Borko Novakovic (MSFT)